# Open Grub menu in debian Stretch at boot time

Tags: debian, boot, grub

I've just installed Debian Stretch 9.5. I've a dual boot (Debian + Windows) and the grub menu worked properly. Since I mainly use Debian I **disabled grub menu** in order to speed up the boot process (edit of the /etc/default/grub file) and it still works properly.

I wonder if there is a way to **open the grub menu at boot time** the few times I need to access Windows, having the grub menu disabled.

I found several posts where they suggested to press and hold Shift button during the boot, but it doesnt't work for me.
Have you any suggestion? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding down shift apparently only works in UEFI mode, so check if that's enabled.

Why not just put a timeout of 1 second for the grub menu. That'll only add 1 second to boot time, but will mean that you can change very easily (pressing any key cancels the timeout).

As root, edit `/etc/default/grub`, set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=1`, and run `update-grub`.

Comment: I tried with UEFI mode but nothing. The solution adpoted is the GRUB_TIMEOUT = 1, thanks @Cyclic3

Comment: @Frederico If it helped, could you mark it as an answer?